# Circle Markers not showing all data

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I've tried to solve this by myself, but can't get the code to work properly.

I got a data frame called `data.cand.map`with 2610 rows that looks like this:

```
head(data.cand.map)
  NR_ZONA NR_LOCAL_VOTACAO.x QT_VOTOS                  ENDEREÇO       lat       lng
1       7               1015        3 RUA ODETE MONTEIRO, N 384 -8.046101 -34.92063
2       7               1015        6 RUA ODETE MONTEIRO, N 384 -8.046101 -34.92063
3       7               1015       11 RUA ODETE MONTEIRO, N 384 -8.046101 -34.92063
4       7               1015        1 RUA ODETE MONTEIRO, N 384 -8.046101 -34.92063
5       7               1015        6 RUA ODETE MONTEIRO, N 384 -8.046101 -34.92063
6       7               1015        5 RUA ODETE MONTEIRO, N 384 -8.046101 -34.92063
```

I want to show all values in the $QT_VOTOS column on the map (by the way `sum(data.cand.map$QT_VOTOS)` is `[1] 14114`, but the maps shows only 2572, as the image below demonstrate:

[map without all data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l4WH.jpg)

code of the map:

```
m <- leaflet(data.cand.map) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
  setView(lng = -34.55, lat = -8.0403, zoom = 10) %>%
  addPolygons(data= mun.latlon,
              color = "Red",
              weight = 1,
              smoothFactor = 1) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = data.cand.map$lng, #circle Markers
                   lat = data.cand.map$lat,
                   color ="ffffff",
                   weight = 1,
                   radius = 5,
                   clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(showCoverageOnHover = FALSE))
m
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looking into the data frame the number 2572 is equal to `sum(data.cand.map$QT_VOTOS[1:573])`, but that does no answer anything...

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you confirm there are 2,610 rows in your data, without skipped numbers in the left most column?

Comment: QT_VOTOS        ENDEREÇO              lon              lat             label          
 Min.   : 1.000   Length:2610        Min.   :-34.99   Min.   :-8.144   Length:2610       
 1st Qu.: 2.000   Class :character   1st Qu.:-34.94   1st Qu.:-8.093   Class :chr  
 Median : 4.000   Mode  :chracter   Median :-34.92   Median :-8.054   Mode  :chr 
 Mean   : 5.408    Mean   :-34.92   Mean   :-8.063                     
 3rd Qu.: 7.000    3rd Qu.:-34.90   3rd Qu.:-8.030                     
 Max.   :27.000    Max.   :-34.88   Max.   :-7.965